# Pattern matching for lambda expressions

Tags: haskell

```
 21 --Primitive recursion constructor
 22 pr :: ([Int] -> Int) -> ([Int] -> Int) -> ([Int] -> Int)
 23 pr f g = \xs 0 -> f xs
 24 pr f g = \xs (y+1) -> g xs y ((pr f g) xs y)
```

I want the function this function creates to act differently on different inputs, so that it can create a recursive function. As expected, the above code doesn't work.  How do I do something like pattern matching, but for the function it creates?

Answer (score 21):

```
pr f g = \xs y' -> case y' of 0     -> f xs
                              (y+1) -> g xs y ((pr f g) xs y)
```

or simply

```
pr f g xs 0 = f xs
pr f g xs (y+1) = g xs y ((pr f g) xs y)
```

(Remember that `f a b = ...` is basically a shortcut for `f a = \b -> ...` which is a shortcut for `f = \a -> \b -> ...`.)

Note that n+1 patterns are deprecated and that the type you specified for pr does not match your (and mine) definition.

Specifically according to your type the function takes an `[Int] -> Int` (f), then a function that takes another `[Int] -> Int` (g), then a function that takes an `[Int]` (xs) and then returning an Int. However you call g with three arguments and the last function that you return takes two arguments, so presumably you want something like `([Int] -> Int) -> ([Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> Int -> Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the lenguaje extension [`LambdaCase`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/lambda_case.html):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

pr f g = \xs -> \case
    0 -> f xs
    (y+1) -> g xs y ((pr f g) xs y)
```

In these case you have two use two `\` because in a `\case` you can have only one argument.