# How to use high order functions with data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

Consider the following data type.

```
data Movement = Credit Float | Debit Float
    deriving Show
```

And now this function.

```
retrieveBiggerThan :: [Movement] -> Float -> [Movement]
retrieveBiggerThan l k = (filter (\(Credit c) -> c>k) l) ++ (filter (\(Debit c) -> c>k) l)
```

If I test this, I receive as output "non-exhaustive patterns in lambda":

```
retrieveBiggerThan [Credit 5.5, Debit 2.3, Credit 3.3] 2

[Credito 5.5*** Exception: ficha7.hs:116:35-53: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda
```

I believe this happens because filter is only expecting for one of the constructors defined in `data Movement`. Is there any chance of doing something like this (a filter able to consider both constructors while checking the list)?

```
filter (\((Credit c) || (Debit c)) -> c > k) listofmovements
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pattern matching for lambda expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801786/pattern-matching-for-lambda-expressions)

Comment: Do you really need seperate `Credit` and `Debit` constructors? Why not a single constructor with positive or negative numbers?

Comment: The syntax you want is a case statement: `\x -> case x of { Credit c -> ..; Debit c -> ..}` - or `\case { ... }` with the LamdbaCase extension. Of course you may end up with a lot of duplication this way, but this is related to your encoding. See comment above mine.

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes, I do need.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`LambdaCase`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html) extension to make the lambda a bit more concise:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

data Movement = Credit Float | Debit Float
    deriving Show

foo = map (\case { Credit f -> f; Debit d -> d}) [Credit 1, Debit 2]
```

Comment: When compiling : parse error on input `case'
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: You're getting a compile error even when using the `LambdaCase` extension? What is your GHC version? It has been available [since GHC 7.6.1](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4359#comment:87).

Answer (score 5):

In this specific case, you could use record syntax.

```
data Movement = Credit { value :: Float } | Debit { value :: Float }
retrieve l k = filter (\mvmt -> value mvmt > k) l
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create a helper called `absMovement` and then just trivially `filter` using that:

```
absMovement :: Movement -> Float
absMovement (Credit c) = c
absMovement (Debit  d) = d

retrieveBiggerThan k =
  filter (\x -> absMovement x > k)
```

(note the curried definition of the function with also its argument order flipped — this is more idiomatic in Haskell for many practical reasons which are beyond the scope of this post)

you can also go point free(r) if you prefer:

```
retrieveBiggerThan k =
  filter $ (k <) . absMovement
```

which reads: *"retrieving bigger than k [of movements] amounts to filtering [of movements] whose absMovement is greater tham k"* — the bracketed phrases correspond to the arguments that were "curried away".

P.S. totally missed that actually using record syntax, you can obtain the `absMovement` function for free, as Daniel Wagner points out; but then again it's nice to think of this as `abs`ing, in my opinion.